# Merit's Galactic Reunion - more mines on mineable planet

Tags: merits-galactic-reunion

I am replaying my old 1990's games, and got most of them working using Dosbox. One of those games is Merit's Galactic Reunion.

I am unable to find a way to put additional mines on a planet that is not suitable for living. The single miner station does not allow for fast mineral build-up for harvesting.

Not hopeful, but I am taking a chance, hoping someone here played that game and can answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mines and their requirements can't be built at all on planets that are not suitable for living: Builder Plant and Vehicle Plant are required for the Spaceport. Spaceport is the only way to add mining robots to mines.

You are left with the only single mining station per such planet.

Try focusing first on building the maximum amounts of mines (9) where possible on accommodable planets with required ores.